# Android Service Running as a separate process

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have a service Class in android. Is it be possible for a Service to run as a separate process than an application just for receiving SMS and enqueue them in a queue after that an application reads SMS from this Queue.

Is it possible to launch a separate service?

I have tag the source code of SmsService class below

public class SmsService extends Service {

```
private SMSReceiver mSMSreceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public SmsService(){
    /*dba = new DataBaseAdapter(this);*/
    mSMSreceiver = new SMSReceiver();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();       

    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(ConstantClass.SMS_RECEIVED);
    registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver,mIntentFilter);
}
@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent , int flags, int type){
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override 
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    //unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);

}
```

Comment: "can it be possible that a Service can run as a seprate process" -- it is possible. It is also a bad idea. A second process consumes more RAM and more CPU while adding no value to the user.

Answer (score 2):

To enroll your service in a different process, you need to define **`android:process`** attribute when defining your service in **AndroidManifest.xml**

For example:

```
<service android:process=":kaushik" />
```

This will run your service in a new process called **kaushik**.

Comment: Sir I have applied process attribute but I am still unable to execute it as a seprate process.this is my code for Manifest.xml <service  android:name=".SmsService" android:process=":zigbee" android:enabled="true" />

Comment: It must be running in a separate process. How are you sure that its not in a separate process?